# How to find out stored procedure names inside a normal stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple stored procedure `Proc_My_SP`:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Results TABLE (Tid INT PRIMARY KEY);

   INSERT @Results

   EXEC Procedure2 [parameters];
   SET @total 1;

END
SELECT @total
```

**Question:** using `Proc_My_SP`, this stored procedure I want to print out `Procedure2` - just the name

If `Proc_My_SP` contains multiple such calls to `Procedure2`, `Procedure3` and others, I want to list out them one by one

Find out all stored procedure names inside a stored procedure and print them

**EDITED**

I have tried to get the text of stored procedure using following way

```
DECLARE @SPTEXT NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SPTEXT = (SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
               WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'Proc_My_SP')
PRINT @SPTEXT
```

But from `@SPTEXT`, how can I find all stored procedure names?

Comment: You could query the text of your stored procedure and find the procedure names getting the next word after the EXEC word

Comment: i have tried to store the text of store procedure in @SPTEXT but from that variable how i can find the exact all  store procedure name check Edited Section i am noob in sql :D

Comment: Check this:`CREATE TABLE #SPs (db_name varchar(100), name varchar(100), object_id int)

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; INSERT INTO #SPs select ''?'', name, object_id from sys.procedures'

SELECT * FROM #SPs`

Comment: @ravishankarchavare Please check my updated answer as I have checked it and giving the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT NAME AS ObjectName
    ,schema_name(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName
    ,type
    ,o.type_desc
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND o.NAME LIKE '%Add%'
    AND type = 'p'
ORDER BY o.NAME
```

OR

```
SELECT NAME AS ObjectName
    ,schema_name(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName
    ,type
    ,o.type_desc
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    --AND o.NAME LIKE '%Add%'
    AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) Like '%YourSearchTextHere%'
    AND type = 'p'
ORDER BY o.NAME
```

The first query will search only in name while second will search anywhere content in SP.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT o.name, dependentObject.name
 FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o on d.id = o.id 
INNER JOIN sysobjects dependentObject on d.depid = dependentObject.id
WHERE o.xtype = 'P' AND dependentObject.xtype = 'P'
```

This query will give you the dependent object name.

Comment: i do not want to search storeprocedure from all sp(from database) i just want to use one single sp and find all storeprocedure name inside that sp

Comment: @ravishankarchavare Thanks for accepting my answer. Using this query you can also search procedure dependent to table. In this case you need to exclude where part or pass xtype = 'U'.